# JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, assertion

```
import React, { isValidElement } from 'react';

interface Props {
    icon: React.ReactNode | React.ElementType;
}

function Button( props: Props ): JSX {

    const { icon: Icon } = props;
    const icon = isValidElement( Icon ) ? Icon : <Icon />

    return (
        <div>{icon}</div>
    );
}
```

The code above throws error on `<Icon />`

```
JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures
```

How can I resolve this and by the way how can I use assertion in JSX like `<Icon as React.ElementType />`?